Woocommerce tax split within same product
as of some complicated tax regulations we nee to split up our taxes within the same Woocommerce product. It's about online courses that combine live- and ondemand-lessons where the live part is free of tax and the ondemand part has a specific tax rate. The tax rate varies per country and per user status private/business.
e.g. a regular product price is 750 €, sale price 700. The taxable part for the regular price ist 200 €, the taxable part for the sale price is 150€. So the product needs to get 0% tax on 550€ and 19% tax (or the respective country rate) on 200€ (or 150€ for sale).
My approach so far ist to implement additional fields in the product meta to define the taxable part of the product price (one for the part of the regular price and one for the part of the sale price) and combine this with the standard tax rates maintained in Woocommerce. This way i can recalculate tax in the cart and checkout, but it conflicts in the admin order view and other places.
any idea how to approach this a smarter way? Thanks for your help!
This is my approach so far:
// Debugging und Initialisierung
add_action('init', 'check_hook_registration');
function check_hook_registration()
{
    error_log('Hooks registered: ' . (has_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_taxes_total_html', 'ysf_adjust_cart_totals_taxes') ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
}

// Hinzufügen der benutzerdefinierten Felder zum Produkt
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'ysf_add_tax_free_fields');
function ysf_add_tax_free_fields()
{
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => 'tax_free_regular_price',
        'class' => 'wc_input_price short',
        'label' => __('Steuerfreier Anteil regulärer Preis in €', 'yogafox'),
        'description' => __('Gib den steuerfreien Anteil des regulären Preises in € ein', 'yogafox'),
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'type' => 'number',
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'step' => 'any',
            'min' => '0'
        )
    ));

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => 'tax_free_sale_price',
        'class' => 'wc_input_price short',
        'label' => __('Steuerfreier Anteil Angebotspreis in €', 'yogafox'),
        'description' => __('Gib den steuerfreien Anteil des Angebotspreises in € ein', 'yogafox'),
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'type' => 'number',
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'step' => 'any',
            'min' => '0'
        )
    ));

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => 'tax_free_description',
        'class' => 'short',
        'label' => __('Beschreibung steuerfreier Anteil', 'yogafox'),
        'description' => __('Beschreibe den steuerfreien Anteil', 'yogafox'),
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'type' => 'text',
    ));

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => 'taxable_description',
        'class' => 'short',
        'label' => __('Beschreibung steuerpflichtiger Anteil', 'yogafox'),
        'description' => __('Beschreibe den steuerpflichtigen Anteil', 'yogafox'),
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'type' => 'text',
    ));
}

// Speichern der benutzerdefinierten Felder im Produkt
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'ysf_save_tax_free_fields');
function ysf_save_tax_free_fields($product)
{
    if (isset($_POST['tax_free_regular_price'])) {
        $product->update_meta_data('tax_free_regular_price', sanitize_text_field($_POST['tax_free_regular_price']));
    }
    if (isset($_POST['tax_free_sale_price'])) {
        $product->update_meta_data('tax_free_sale_price', sanitize_text_field($_POST['tax_free_sale_price']));
    }
    if (isset($_POST['tax_free_description'])) {
        $product->update_meta_data('tax_free_description', sanitize_text_field($_POST['tax_free_description']));
    }
    if (isset($_POST['taxable_description'])) {
        $product->update_meta_data('taxable_description', sanitize_text_field($_POST['taxable_description']));
    }
}

// Überprüfen, ob ein Produkt steuerfreie Beträge hat
function ysf_has_tax_free_amount($product)
{
    $tax_free_amount = floatval($product->get_meta('tax_free_' . ($product->is_on_sale() ? 'sale' : 'regular') . '_price'));
    return $tax_free_amount > 0;
}

// Berechnung der angepassten Steuer
function ysf_calculate_adjusted_tax($price, $tax_free_amount, $tax_rate)
{
    $taxable_amount = $price - $tax_free_amount;
    return $taxable_amount * ($tax_rate / (1 + $tax_rate));
}

// Anpassung der Steuerberechnung für Warenkorb-Artikel
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price_including_tax', 'ysf_adjust_product_price_including_tax', 10, 3);
function ysf_adjust_product_price_including_tax($price, $qty, $product)
{
    if (ysf_has_tax_free_amount($product)) {
        $tax_free_amount = floatval($product->get_meta('tax_free_' . ($product->is_on_sale() ? 'sale' : 'regular') . '_price'));
        $tax_rates = WC_Tax::get_rates($product->get_tax_class());
        $tax_rate = reset($tax_rates)['rate'] / 100;

        $adjusted_tax = ysf_calculate_adjusted_tax($price, $tax_free_amount, $tax_rate);
        return $price - ($price - $tax_free_amount) + $adjusted_tax;
    }
    return $price;
}

// Anpassung der Anzeige der Warenkorb-Artikelpreise
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'ysf_adjust_cart_item_price', 10, 3);
function ysf_adjust_cart_item_price($price_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)
{
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    if (ysf_has_tax_free_amount($product)) {
        $price = $product->get_price();
        $tax_free_amount = floatval($product->get_meta('tax_free_' . ($product->is_on_sale() ? 'sale' : 'regular') . '_price'));
        $tax_rates = WC_Tax::get_rates($product->get_tax_class());
        $tax_rate = reset($tax_rates)['rate'] / 100;

        $adjusted_tax = ysf_calculate_adjusted_tax($price, $tax_free_amount, $tax_rate);

        $tax_free_description = $product->get_meta('tax_free_description');
        $taxable_description = $product->get_meta('taxable_description');

        $price_html .= '<br><small>';
        $price_html .= sprintf(__('%s: %s', 'yogafox'), $tax_free_description, wc_price($tax_free_amount)) . '<br>';
        $price_html .= sprintf(
            __('%s: %s (inkl. %s%% MwSt: %s)', 'yogafox'),
            $taxable_description,
            wc_price($price - $tax_free_amount),
            number_format($tax_rate * 100, 2),
            wc_price($adjusted_tax)
        );
        $price_html .= '</small>';
    }
    return $price_html;
}

// Anpassung der Steuerberechnung für den gesamten Warenkorb
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_get_taxes', 'ysf_adjust_cart_taxes', 10, 2);
function ysf_adjust_cart_taxes($taxes, $cart)
{
    $adjusted_taxes = array();
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if (ysf_has_tax_free_amount($product)) {
            $price = $product->get_price();
            $tax_free_amount = floatval($product->get_meta('tax_free_' . ($product->is_on_sale() ? 'sale' : 'regular') . '_price'));
            $tax_rates = WC_Tax::get_rates($product->get_tax_class());
            $tax_rate = reset($tax_rates)['rate'] / 100;

            $adjusted_tax = ysf_calculate_adjusted_tax($price, $tax_free_amount, $tax_rate) * $cart_item['quantity'];

            $rate_id = key($tax_rates);
            if (!isset($adjusted_taxes[$rate_id])) {
                $adjusted_taxes[$rate_id] = 0;
            }
            $adjusted_taxes[$rate_id] += $adjusted_tax;
        } else {
            $item_taxes = WC_Tax::calc_tax($cart_item['line_total'], WC_Tax::get_rates($product->get_tax_class()), true);
            foreach ($item_taxes as $rate_id => $tax) {
                if (!isset($adjusted_taxes[$rate_id])) {
                    $adjusted_taxes[$rate_id] = 0;
                }
                $adjusted_taxes[$rate_id] += $tax;
            }
        }
    }
    return $adjusted_taxes;
}

// Anpassung der Steueranzeige im Warenkorb und an der Kasse
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_taxes_total_html', 'ysf_adjust_cart_totals_taxes', 10, 2);
function ysf_adjust_cart_totals_taxes($tax_total_html, $cart)
{
    $adjusted_taxes = ysf_adjust_cart_taxes(array(), $cart);
    $adjusted_tax_total = array_sum($adjusted_taxes);
    return wc_price($adjusted_tax_total);
}


